# Reading non-js files in node js with combination of typescript and webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I have a backend NodeJS setup written in TypeScript and using webpack to compile it.

When I try to read a text file I get this error while I made sure that source/test.txt is getting copied to build folder.

Error:

```
fs.js:640
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/source/test.txt'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
```

My Project Structure

```
project
-- build
-- server
---- server.tsx
---- source
------ test.txt
```

server.tsx

```
import * as express from 'express'
import * as Path from 'path'
import * as fs from 'fs'

const app = express()

const textFile = fs.readFileSync(Path.join(__dirname, "./source/test.txt"))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`running on port 3000`))
```

**$ webpack && node build/server.js**

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./server/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const Path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./server/server.tsx",
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        filename: "server.js",
        path: __dirname + "/build"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader" },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: Path.join(__dirname, './server/source'), to: Path.join(__dirname, './build/source') }
      ])
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__dirname` is being set to `/` by webpack. Currently it tries to find `/source/test.txt` as the error messages says, which is the root of your file system. You can tell webpack not to inject the `__dirname` by setting `node.dirname` to `false`, so it will correctly use the Node.js `__dirname`:

```
node: {
  __dirname: false
}
```